# SSMS crashes when opening Design Query Editor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, crash, ssms

is there a fix for the crash in SQL-Server 2005 Management Studio when you try to open a design-query-editor with a sql-statementent preceding `USE database;`?

For example:

```
USE DB1;
SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

If you mark `SELECT * FROM Table1;`, you can open the editor succesfully.
If you mark both lines, SSMS will crash with a "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio has stopped working"-Dialog(with the option to debug or close SSMS)  and some additional information on this problem f.e.:

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: SqlWb.exe
  Application Version:  2005.90.5000.0
  Application Timestamp:    4d02772b
  Fault Module Name:    vdt80.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.0.50727.1826
  Fault Module Timestamp:   480d6e41
  Exception Offset: 0032ae42
  Exception Code:   c0000409
  Exception Data:   00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.16.7
```

**SQL-Server** version:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
9.00.5000.00       SP4       Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
```

**OS**:

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard(SP 1)
```

**Edit**: this problem also occurs if i try to open the designer with T-SQL Statement like:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM ClosingDate
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()). ClosingDate) = 0
) UPDATE Table2 SET
    Column1 = 255
WHERE
    Column1 = 1
```

Comment: Never had that issue myself. This may sound a bit flippant but have you tried to reinstall SSMS

Comment: Do you have the latest [service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b953e84f-9307-405e-bceb-47bd345baece&displaylang=en) installed?

Comment: @Joe: Yes i have. Edited my question and added the sql-server- and OS-Version.
@AgentDBA: Not so far. I thought that this would be a known issue. On the other hand i don't want to reinstall SSMS only for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, take out the use db statement and change the code to this:

```
select * from DB1.dbo.Table1
```

this syntax will allow you to select data from other databases on the same server in which you are not in the context of.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, there are workarounds to this issue. But if i would remember that everytime, this wouldn't be an issue. I could also remember not to mark the `USE DB` when opening the editor.

Comment: well i tried to duplicate but i just get an error message.  http://i.imgur.com/b6Stx.png  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      2007.0100.1600.022 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      8.0.7600.16385
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.4952
Operating System      6.1.7600