# Deleting all but one record of duplicate entries

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Server 2005 and would like to delete duplicate records that have the oldest dates.  For example, I have a training database that captures an employee number, class name and date.  Some folks have taken the class more than once, but we only need to keep the record of the latest class attendance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a [`CTE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  ID, Scan, TrainingDate, TrainingType, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By Scan, TrainingType 
                                Order By TrainingDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.SETD_SimpleScan
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rn > 1
```

Replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *` to see what you're going to delete.

Comment: I don't understand the answer.  My table name is SETD_SimpleScan.  The columns are ID (PK), Scan, TrainingDate and TrainingType. How would the query look with this info?

Comment: I want to delete the records that contain the earlier TrainingDate for each TrainingType for each Scan.

Comment: The query parses but when I go to run it, SQL Server Managment Studio closes.

Comment: @PeggyHall: it works without a problem in SQL-Server 2005(i'm also using it). But the editor in SSMS crashes if you use it there. At least i have this problem, i've even [asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091742/ssms-crashes-when-opening-design-query-editor) here some time ago. Just design and run it in the normal query window.

Comment: The query ran and showed 674 row affected, but there are still duplicte trainings for some scans.

Comment: Disregard my last post.  All duplicates are now gone!  That was so cool!!! Not sure why it worked but very thankful that it did!